Production Build/run in Expo causes layout to break
I'm using Tamagui and Expo to develop a web/android/ios application. Running the application with npx expo start (whether through the emulator, expo go, or dev server), everything goes perfectly, and the layout is exactly in the format I built on all platforms. However,  when I build to production (with EAS) or run npx expo start --no-dev --minify to simulate the production environment, the layout is completely broken, as if the style of the components were not being applied, or at least not correctly.
I've already tried:
• Deleting node_modules
• Solving all dependency issues listed in the yarn check and npm audit
• Updating all dependencies (as much as possible to maintain compatibility)
• Importing tamagui.css in the layout
• npx tamagui-build
• npx expo prebuild
and a few other solutions, but all failed.
